# PowerBuilder Datawindow Crashes when Opening

Tags: powerbuilder

I've been working on a payroll system right now and been modifying a ledger type datawindow. Suddenly, after testing the data the powerbuilder crashes...

What i have done is uncheck the "Remember the retrieval argument" but to no avail. Every time im opening the datawindow, the application crashes.

what fix can I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe some of the programmer here who are new to powerbuilder might be asking this but to solve this problem, you have to delete the datawindow registry key in regedit. the key is located at HKEY_CURRENT_USER/SOFTWARE/Sybase/Layout/Default

There you will see at least 9 registry key. Close you powerbuilder IDE and then delete the Datawindow key. Open you PowerBuilder IDE again and it should get rid of the Datawindow crashing down.

Thanks!

Comment: Good ol' buggy PowerBuilder.  I'll have to remember this as I run in to this occasionally (though definitely not nearly as often as I used to in older versions.)  I think I have usually done something with INI files hidden somewhere in AppData but I forget exactly.

Comment: Worked great.  The modern reg key is...
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Sybase\PowerBuilder\21.0\Layout\Default